# IPTables/Route and multiple interfaces configuration

Tags: interface, routes, iptables, gateway

I've this scenario, a Debian box running with multiple network cards:

1. **eth0** - Internet Connection via local Router (172.20.1.x , 255.255.255.0)
2. **ppp0** - Dial-up to a network without internet (10.x.x.x , 255.255.255.255)
3. **tun0** - Virtual OpenVPN Tun interface (172.50.1.x, 255.255.255.255)

My goal is to allow clients to connect to the VPN over ppp0 and forward their internet traffic to eth0.

Right now, clients can connect to the VPN and they are able to reach the router on eth0 172.20.1.1, but they can't get to google or anywhere else on the internet. (And no, it's not a DNS issue. I tried the IP)

How can I setup iptables/route to allow this?

I think the problem is related to routing because on the debian machine I can ping and access the router (172.20.1.1) too, but I don't have internet access.

```
root@shv1:~# ping 172.20.1.1
PING 172.20.1.1 (172.20.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.20.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.416 ms
64 bytes from 172.20.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.428 ms
^C
--- 172.20.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.416/0.422/0.428/0.006 ms
root@shv1:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.34.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3003ms

root@shv1:~# ping 173.194.34.197
PING 173.194.34.197 (173.194.34.197) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 173.194.34.197 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2004ms
```

I also tried to change the default gateway to the router IP (172.20.1.1) using this:

```
route add default gw 172.20.1.1 eth0
```

Now I can access the internet but then clients can't connect or ping my machine over the dial-up connection (ppp0).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I managed to solve this issue by:

```
route add default gw 172.20.1.1 eth0
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 ppp0
```

This sets my default gateway on eth0 and it's router and adds a new route for the 10.x.x.x network.

This way I'm able to reach the internet and still be accessible over the ppp0 dial-up.